# Uncaught Error: [vee-validate] No such validator '1234567' exists

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vee-validate to validate the register form and i have made the code as follows,

```
        <form @submit.prevent="signUp()">
          <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('register.mobile_number') }" >
            <input v-model="register.mobile_number" v-validate="register.mobile_number" data-vv-rules="required" required class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('register.email') }" >
            <input v-model="register.email" v-validate="register.email" class="form-control" type="email" data-vv-rules="required|email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('register.password') }" >
            <input v-model="register.password" v-validate="register.password" name="password" data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('register.confirm_password') }" >
            <input v-model="register.confirm_password" v-validate="register.confirm_password" name="confirm_password" data-vv-as="password" data-vv-rules="required|confirmed:password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer btn-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

And the script was:

```
export default {
data() {
return {
register: {
        mobile_number: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirm_password: '',
      },
}
},
  methods: {
signUp() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
      });
      axios.post(config.apiDomain+'/Home',this.register).then(response=>{
      });
    }
},
}
```

And also imported vee-validate in main.js as,

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

But if we enter anything inside the input box, it is throwing error as

```
Uncaught Error: [vee-validate] No such validator '12312321' exists.
```

Whatever thing i enter inside any of the input box, it is showing the same error. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is incorrectly specifying the validation rules. For example here:

```
<input v-model="register.mobile_number" v-validate="register.mobile_number" data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
```

The code is saying that the validation rule should be whatever is in `register.mobile_number` because of this: `v-validate="register.mobile_number"`.

Instead, you should specify the name(s) of the validation rules to use.

```
<input v-model="register.mobile_number" v-validate="'required'" class="form-control" type="number" name="Mobile Number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
```

Note that I added `name="Mobile Number"` because either `name` or `data-vv-name` is required, and I removed `data-vv-rules` because it is [deprecated](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#data-attributes).

All of this is covered directly in the [basic example](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/index.html#basic-example) in the documentation.

Comment: The password confirmation input box is not working, whatever values we give in confirm password, it is not validating..

Comment: @ManiRaj That's a separate question. Not knowing how you've set up your code after taking my recommendations above into account, its difficult to answer.

Comment: I have made changes from your answer but password validation not working,and i have updated my code in my question..

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar error in VeeValidate 3, and the problem is that I forgot to include the rules in the import statement and then extend them like this:

```
import { required, email, integer, between } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', required);
extend('email', email);
extend('integer', integer);
extend('between', between);
```

In case someone else does the same mistake.

Comment: I had  include extend as well

Comment: When I use extend, it seems I don't have the expected default message for a rule anymore.
For example 'min', seems like it should say 'The {field} field must be at least 4 characters'.

Do we have to specify all our messages now in VeeValidate 3, in order to get anything besides the  default 'This field is invalid' [message](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#messages)?